# How to sort field from multiple Channels?

Tags: channel-entries

I'm looping through multiple Channels:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_a|channel_b"}
```

Say that `channel_a` has `a_field` and `channel_b` has `b_field`. I want to sort such that the values of `a_field` and `b_field` are consider part of the same list. I don't want to, say, sort all the `a_field` first, then all the `b_field` next.

Possible to do this in EE?

Comment: Simple question: can't you use the same field group to both channels?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's not an option for me. Should I enable PHP in the template and try to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job to [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash)!

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="channels_a_and_b" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_a|channel_b"}
                {stash:sort_field}{a_field}{b_field}{/stash:sort_field}
                {stash:another_field_a}{another_field}{/stash:another_field_a}
                {stash:another_field_b}{another_field}{/stash:another_field_b}
                [...]
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then, on an embed:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="channels_a_and_b" orderby="sort_field"}
    {sort_field}
    {another_field_a}
    {another_field_b}
    [...]
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Just, please, don't get addicted to Stash. I have seen a lot of unnecessary and complex uses of Stash around there.